# Pygal SolidGuage - Changing Label Font Size

Tags: python, graph, charts, flask, pygal

I'm using Pygal's SolidGuage chart to display a value between two ranges. See the link below for an image of the chart.

[Pygal Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CzzW.png)

I'm trying to make the font size for the labels (0 & 12%) larger.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I can't seem to find the right command in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for all of the help!

Comment: you can use value_font_size for changing the font size, refer given link: http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/solidgauge.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set font size in constructor

```
gauge = pygal.SolidGauge(
        half_pie=True, inner_radius=0.70,
        style=pygal.style.styles['default'](value_font_size=8),
        show_legend=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

chart = pygal.Bar(style=pygal.style.styles'default')